# torquebox for production. Anyone?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jruby

I want to migrate my infrastructure to jRuby. The most complete options as I see is torquebox. Anyone can share something about it? compared to tomcat/jetty?

Comment: I wrote this as a comment because it's not a real answer but, torquebox is JBoss a little modified for rack app. We use JBoss intensively in test and production and it's stable and incredibly easy to cluster and control. It's a wonderful solution for production.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am using TorqueBox 1.0 Release Candidate for 24x7 mission critical production solutions.  It has been adopted as the platform of choice for all new development on my project, replacing a very expensive commercial ESB.  Although HornetQ is not (yet) replacing our business's enterprise JMS provider, we are using HornetQ heavily to a growing collection of loosely coupled JRuby components.

In my view, TorqueBox is a superb blend of a world class application server with high-availability features built-in, a high performance messaging server (HA-JMS, HA-JNDI), and my favorite programming language.

As a bonus, my productivity has soared since working almost exclusively in JRuby.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm currently making deploys 3 or 4 times a day, how much time needs Torquebox to deploy a new version? Can be automated with tools like capistrano? Thanks!

Comment: With the latest builds of TorqueBox you can essentially do war file deployments by archiving your code on a dev or test server and deploying the war (actually a "knob" in TorqueBox parlance) to a running production TorqueBox server. I'm seeing times of about two-and-a-minutes for TorqueBox to terminate the instance of our (relatively small) application and launch the new instance. Faster would be better, but we can live with that performance. Especially given the development-time productivity benefits of having built in support for things like messaging, asynchronous tasks and scheduled tasks.

Answer (score 3):

We are using Torquebox 2.x with Sunspot/Solr for a number of [search based websites](http://www.nottsinfoscript.co.uk/) for the NHS (UK). These sites have very high page views and caching is difficult so mostly we serve dynamic content.

I would highly recommend JRuby/Torquebox

1. Torquebox has excellent support via IRC and the Mailing list
2. Torquebox is open source, but commerically backed by Redhat
3. Torquebox makes infrastructure easy, no separate message queue, background processes out of the box etc. etc.
4. JRuby is threadsafe and fast
5. JRuby has access to all the Java libraries (we use jsoup, fly saucer for PDF generation)

Answer (score 1):

We also use jboss AS7 (not Torquebox) with HornetQ and a mixed jruby java environment in critical projects for production. Assynchronous processes a treated in java in the background, the rest in jruby on rails (frontend stuff - user interaction)
It will go live this year.